# How to list a product that is click and collect?

Tags: .net, ebay-api

I am a .Net developer trying to list a product on eBay that is Click & Collect. My code snippet is:

```
Dim ServiceOption As New ShippingServiceOptionsType() 
ebayItem.ShippingDetails = New ShippingDetailsType() ebayItem.ShippingDetails.ShippingServiceOptions = New ShippingServiceOptionsTypeCollection() 
ServiceOption.ShippingService = "PickUpDropOff" 
ebayItem.AutoPay = True 
ebayItem.PickupInStoreDetails = New PickupInStoreDetailsType() ebayItem.PickupInStoreDetails.EligibleForPickupDropOff = True ebayItem.ShippingDetails.ShippingServiceOptions.Add(ServiceOption)
```

I am getting error message:

```
Postage service Click & Collect(370) is not available.One or more parameter values in the input request are invalid. Check the response for ErrorParameters elements to determine which parameters have invalid values. Correct these values, and then resend the input request.
```

Does anyone know what is missing in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Enabling *Click & Collect* on the UK site is not done by setting a shipping service. This feature is activated by the [EligibleForPickupDropOff](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/AddFixedPriceItem.html#Request.Item.PickupInStoreDetails.EligibleForPickupDropOff) field. Ignore the *EligibleForPickupInStore* field, unless the seller has the ability for buyers to pick up items from the seller's store.

With regards to choosing a shipping service never rely on the documentation for [ShippingServiceCodeType](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/reference/ebay/types/ShippingServiceCodeType.html) to be up to date. At it says:

> Applications should not depend on the completeness of
>   ShippingServiceCodeType. Instead, applications should call
>   GeteBayDetails, with a DetailName value of ShippingServiceDetails, to
>   return the complete list of shipping services.

The error you are seeing is because shipping services are not compatible across sites and not all services available to a site can be used to list an item. This is what the error message `Postage service Click & Collect(370) is not available` means. You will have to use a valid service which can be determined by using the API.

- Call [GeteBayDetails](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GeteBayDetails.html) with the [DetailName](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GeteBayDetails.html#Request.DetailName) field set to [ShippingServiceDetails](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/types/DetailNameCodeType.html). Ensure that you send this request to the site that you are listing on.
- Iterate through each [ShippingServiceDetails](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GeteBayDetails.html#Response.ShippingServiceDetails) element in the response.
- For each *ShippingServiceDetails* element check that the [ValidForSellingFlow](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GeteBayDetails.html#Response.ShippingServiceDetails.ValidForSellingFlow) field is true as this means you can use the shipping service in your AddItem calls.
- Read the value of the [ShippingService](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GeteBayDetails.html#Response.ShippingServiceDetails.ShippingService) field. This value will be what you can pass via the AddItem call.

As a short cut I do maintain a list of [shipping services for all sites](http://devbay.net/developers/tools/ebay-details/ShippingServiceDetails/) that has been built from the API. You can use this to determine which services are valid. To be on the safe side I would still recommend using the API to keep you own list of valid shipping services otherwise you will be relying on me to keep my site up to date!

For anyone who has problems in trying to figure out how to build an AddItem request I would recommend the following method. Use eBay itself to construct a listing. This can be either on the sandbox or one of the test categories on the live site. The aim is to create a listing that has the information that you are trying to list via the API. E.g A set of item specifics or a feature such as Click & Collect. Once the item has been listed use it's item ID to pull back the data via GetItem. The structure of the XML response and the value of the fields can be used to determine how to construct your AddItem requests. 99% of the time there is a direct mapping of information in GetItem to AddItem.

Comment: Thank you so much David. I will try this out.